# When users are removed are the votes they had cast on comments removed as well?

Tags: support, comments, users, votes

I know that when users get removed the votes they had cast on posts are usually removed. Actually it happens more often than not but I know this too that sometimes removal of votes doesn't happen. There is some criteria that decides whether the votes will be removed or retained but I'm not aware of what exactly that is.

But this question is about the votes that the user had cast on comments. When some  user is removed are their votes on comments retained or removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short Answer: No the votes on the comments don't get removed when the user is removed.

Long Answer: [Comment votes can be easily gamed by users with the association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296204/206319)